# Vite Vue3 change boolean

Tags: vue.js, indexing, vuejs3, vite

Can somebody please tell me how I have to write the "doneChange" method that I can access on the individual index of the tasks list to change the boolean of finish from true to false and viceversa?

My Code:

```html
<template>
<div>
<h1>Alle Aufgaben</h1>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(task, index) in tasks" :class="{ 'done' : task.finish}">
                <p>{{task.description}}</p>
                <button class="doneChange" @click="doneChange(index)">✓</button>
                <button class="del" @click="del(index)">X</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, reactive, computed } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    let tasks = [
            {description: "Frühstücken", finish: true},
            {description: "Lernen", finish: false},
            {description: "Trainieren", finish: false},
            {description: "Einkaufen", finish: false},
            {description: "Mails", finish: false},
            {description: "Abendessen", finish: false},
        ];

    const del = (index) => this.tasks.splice(index,1);
    const doneChange = (index) => tasks(index).finish = !tasks(index).finish;

        return { tasks, del, doneChange };
    }
};
</script>
```

With this I get the error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: tasks is not a function
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the parentheses after a symbol invokes a function:

```js
tasks(index).finish = !tasks(index).finish  // ❌ calls a function named `tasks`
     ^     ^                ^     ^
```

Instead of parentheses, use square brackets to reference an array element by index:

```js
tasks[index].finish = !tasks[index].finish
```

Also `tasks` should be a `reactive` prop so that its changes causes a re-render:

```js
let tasks = reactive([/*...*/])
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-render-list-changes?file=src/App.vue)